# How to strike through a completed list item in To-Do App?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to strike through the completed list item in react based todo app . I had tried many ways to do this but in the end the Done button not doing anything. The done button not giving any error in the console log it just not doing anything that making me confuse to sort the error

```
export default class Todo extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            text: "",
            todoList: [],
            completed: {
            }
        }
    }
    handleText = (e) => {
        this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
    };

    addTodo = () => {
        let { text, todoList } = this.state;
        let list = [...todoList];
        list.push(text);
        this.setState({ todoList: list, text: "" })
    };

    delTodo = index => () => {
        alert(index);
        const list2 = [...this.state.todoList];
        list2.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({ todoList: list2 })
    };
```

The below handleCheck function i had made to check the whether item is completed or not but its not doing anything.

```
handleCheck(index) {
    // code to create line through completed item
    this.setState(state => ({
        completed: { ...this.state.completed, [index]: !state.completed[index] }
    }));
}


render() {
    let { text, todoList } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="App-header">
            <div className="childApp">
                <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>To-Do APP!</h1>
                <h3>You have {todoList.length} Todos</h3>
                <br />
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {todoList.map((val, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="mytodo">
                                <li key={index} className="list-group-item">
                                    <span className="spname"> {val} </span>
                                    <button id={index} className="btn btn-default btn-s pull-right remove-item" onClick={this.delTodo(index)}>
                                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" onChange={() => this.handleCheck(index)} className="btn btn-default btn-s pull-right remove-item">Done</button>
                                </li>
                                {/* <li key={index} className="displaylist">{val}</li>
                 <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>          */}
                            </div>
                        );
                    }

                    )}
                </ul>
                <br />
                <h4>Add a new To-Do</h4>
                <input className="todoinput" name="text" value={text} placeholder="Enter new task" onChange={this.handleText} />
                <br />

                <button type="button" onClick={this.addTodo} className="btn">Add Todo</button>

                <br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    );}}
```

Comment: onClick={() => this.delTodo(index)}

Comment: Don't use `index` value of `map`, it'll mess up everything for you.

Comment: then what should i use

Answer (score 0):

```
  const handleCheck = event => {
    if (event.target.style.textDecoration) {
      event.target.style.removeProperty('text-decoration');
    } else {
      event.target.style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
      event.target.style.setProperty("color", "green");

    }
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).